# Mocking select with expectations in rspec unit test

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, mocking

Please do correct me if I'm phrasing the question poorly.

Assume the following code:

```
class Filters
  def self.good ducks
    ducks.select(&:good?)
  end
end
```

It is of course possible to test the method like this:

```
describe Filters, '#good' do
  let(:good) { double(:good, good?: true) }
  let(:bad)  { double(:bad, good?: false) }

  subject { Filters.good(ducks) }

  context 'none' do
    let(:ducks) { [] }
    it { is_expected.to eq [] }
  end

  context 'one good' do
    let(:ducks) { [good] }
    it { is_expected.to eq [good] }
  end

  context 'one bad' do
    let(:ducks) { [bad] }
    it { is_expected.to eq [] }
  end

  context 'one good and one bad' do
    let(:ducks) { [good, bad] }
    it { is_expected.to eq [good] }
  end

  context 'some good and some bad' do
    let(:ducks) { [good, bad, bad, good, bad, good] }
    it { is_expected.to eq [good, good, good] }
  end
end
```

But enumerating all of the cases (of course not actually all but none/one/some/many for combinations of true/false `good` states) makes me feel that I am in fact not *unit* testing the method but *integration* testing it since I'm letting knowledge of the behavior of `select` "leak" into my `good` method causing the number of test cases to multiply. In some sense my test cases are testing the behaviour of the `select` method.

To me it seems more appropriate to instead use mocking and check (as in checking rather than testing) that the method delegates correctly. As one could do if one was integrating with a function written by oneself. Something similar to how we e.g. can say `expect(obj).to receive(:foo).with(:bar)`.

The example below doesn't work but I believe it conveys the idea of what I want to do instead of enumerating all cases.

```
describe Filters, '#good' do
  it 'returns only good ones' do
    ducks = double(:ducks)
    expect(ducks).to receive(:filter).with(:good?).and_return(:filtered)
    expect(Filters.good(ducks).to eq )
  end
end
```

The example may seem to trivial so to avoid arguments saying that it is a useless method and that the user of `Filter.good` simply should use `select` directly, please consider the fact that moving the `select`-statement only moves the need for the test to another location.

Am I misunderstanding or overlooking something fundamental here?

Ps 1. I'm ignoring some test cases for brevity.

Ps 2. the short version of the reason I'm emphasizing the need to *unit* and not *integration* test is this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VDfX44fZoMc

EDIT:
A better way to phrase this question would perhaps be: The first test is an example of the gist of how a *classicist* would test `Filters.good`, but how would a *mockist* test it?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @PaulFioravanti Thank you for the answer you've provided. But it seems to me that there is no solution yet. I'm adding a clarification to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve but I would look into using Factory girl and in particular Factory girls create_list. modifying the one to be bad. https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md
and if you really wanted can expect each one to have :good? called on it. 
It might be nicer just to ensure your list at the end only has good ones in it. 
Giving a real world example of what your doing might help but I think creating a factory girl list will satisfy at least one of your issues.

Modified:

```
let(:duck){double :duck}
describe Filters, '#good' do
  it 'returns only good ones' do
    ducks = [duck, duck, duck]
    expect(ducks).to receive(:good).exactly(3).times
    Filters.good(ducks)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've rephrased the question and added examples.

Comment: Ok, I'll modify my answer :P

Answer (score 0):

Since the method under test does filtering, I think you can get a succinct single unit test written without any need for stubbing any code in the method (aside from the response of `good?` by any element of the collection that gets passed in) by testing for the inclusion (or lack thereof) of an object in your result set:

```ruby
class Filters
  def self.good(ducks)
    ducks.select(&:good?)
  end
end

RSpec.describe Filters do
  describe '.good' do
    let(:good_duck) { double(:good, good?: true) }
    let(:bad_duck) { double(:bad, good?: false) }
    let(:ducks) { [good_duck, bad_duck] }
    let(:good) { described_class.good(ducks) }

    it 'returns only good ducks' do
      expect(good).to include(good_duck)
      expect(good).not_to include(bad_duck)
    end
  end
end
```

The spec doesn't care how many good or bad ducks are in the collection that is passed to the `Filters.good` method: it only cares that any object that responds to `good?` with `true` is in the result set, and any object that responds with `false` is not, eliminating the need for the `context` blocks outlined in the question, except perhaps for the `context` that tests an empty array.

Comment: But this would give a false positive for the implementation: `[ducks.first]`, which would again suggest the need to test multiple cases.

Comment: @chris Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "a false positive for the implementation: `[ducks.first]`".  Where does an array with the first element of a collection play into this?

Comment: The test passes (incorrectly) if the implementation of `Filters.good(ducks)` is `[ducks.first]`.

Comment: Aren't you then completely changing the method implementation and hence would need a completely different test?  The current implementation of `Filters.good(ducks)` is the return value of `ducks.select(&:good?)`, but you want to change the implementation to the return value of `[ducks.first]`?  Sorry, I still don't get it...

Comment: The intent of a test is to increase the likelihood that the implementation of a method is not changed to something that does not adhere to the specification. If the method does not adhere to the spec then we should see a failing test. The specification in this case (sorry for not being clear) is that an array of only the ducks that respond `true` to the message `good?` should be returned. With the test above we would not get a failing test if the implementation was changed to the incorrect implementation `def good(ducks); [ducks.first]; end`.

Comment: My argument is that, using a mockist approach I should be able to get closer to "verifying" (as in verification rather than testing) that the method behaves accordingly, as opposed to a classicist approach that would test (as in testing rather than verification) a few well-selected cases.

Comment: But I can't figure out how to syntactically do the mockist style testing in Ruby. If functions were first-class it would be trivial. But the only OO solution I can think of involves creating another class but I'm asking since I'm hoping I'm overlooking some other solution :)